# boost::filesystem calls are seg-faulting in Destructor

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2005, filesystems

I have a wrapper class which makes a temporary copy of a file.  I'd like it to be erased on destruction, but Boost is seg faulting on each call to boost filesystem.

```
MyWrapperClass::~MyWrapperClass()
{
  //if(boost::filesystem::exists("path/to/file.txt"))  //this seg-faults
  //if(boost::filesystem::exists(_pathString))         //so does this
  {
    boost::filesystem::remove(_pathString);            //this also seg faults
  }
}
```

The `_pathString` variable is the same one used to create the copy of the file in the first place.  In the debugger, it appears that the path string is indeed correct.  Each of these filesystem functions pass through `path_traits::dispatch` (boost version 1_49_0 path.hpp line 135)

I don't know if I'm on to something here, but following the call stack down into the weeds, I come to `boost_1_49_0\libs\filesystem\v3\src\path_traits.cpp`.  The `convert_aux` function on line 63 creates `const char* from_next;` and passes it to a function `in` without initializing it.  The debugger says this evaluates to a bad pointer, and the seg-fault is occurring in the definition of `in` in `Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\crt\src\xlocale`.

Any ideas why this is happening?  Could this be a bug in boost or is it more likely that boost is having trouble with my seven year old visual studio?

Comment: My 2 cents are on this being a linking mismatch: linking against different version boost libs, threading model mismatch between your exe & the boost libs, that kind of stuff.

Comment: Just a general remark: All of those boost functions may throw, which you don't want to happen in a destructor. Consider using the two-argument, non-throwing versions of the respecting functions, which return error codes instead. See the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#Error-reporting) for details.